# Storing a JS Callback to be called later in Node C++ Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, objective-c, objective-c++, node-addon-api

I'm creating a Node C++ addon for macOS, so I'm using Objective-C mixed with C++ and the Node Addon API.

I want to provide a function for Node JS, that receives a callback to be called later when an Obj-C observer is called. This is how I tried to achieve this:

```
#include <node.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface JSCallback:NSObject {
  //Instance variables
  NSString *testStr;
  v8::Local<v8::Context> context;
  v8::Local<v8::Function> fn;
  v8::Isolate* isolate;
}
@property(retain, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *testStr;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) v8::Local<v8::Context> context;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) v8::Local<v8::Function> fn;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) v8::Isolate* isolate;
@end

@implementation JSCallback
@synthesize testStr;
@synthesize context;
@synthesize fn;
@synthesize isolate;
@end

namespace demo {

using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Function;
using v8::Context;
using v8::Value;

static OSStatus audioOutputDeviceChanged(
  AudioObjectID inObjectID,
  UInt32 inNumberAddresses,
  const AudioObjectPropertyAddress* inAddresses,
  void* __nullable inClientData
) {
  JSCallback *jsCb = *((__unsafe_unretained JSCallback **)(&inClientData));
  printf("%s", [jsCb.testStr UTF8String]);
  jsCb.fn->Call(jsCb.context, Null(jsCb.isolate), 0, {}).ToLocalChecked();
  return noErr;
}

void setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
    kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster,
  };

  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
  Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
  // cb->Call(context, Null(isolate), 0, {}).ToLocalChecked();

  JSCallback *jsCb = [[JSCallback alloc]init];

  jsCb.testStr = @"a test string #002";
  jsCb.context = context;
  jsCb.fn = cb;
  jsCb.isolate = isolate;


  OSStatus status = AudioObjectAddPropertyListener(
    kAudioObjectSystemObject,
    &address,
    &audioOutputDeviceChanged,
    jsCb
  );

  if (status != noErr) {
    NSException *e = [NSException
      exceptionWithName:@"OSStatus Error"
      reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OSStatus Error (status: %d)", status]
      userInfo:nil];

    @throw e;
  }
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange", setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)

}
```

I created the `JSCallback` class to hold the variables needed to trigger the JS callback function. And then pass it as the `inClientData` for `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener`.

Then when `audioOutputDeviceChanged` is called, I try to trigger the JS callback using the variables I stored. However, when I do so, the JS script crashes, and only prints the following (no stack trace):

```
#
# Fatal error in v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle()
# Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
#
```

I think this could be happening because when `setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange` returns, it deallocates (or something of the sort) the variables (context, cb, and isolate). And thus they're unusable outside of the function. How can I get around this?

If needed, here's my JS code that uses the addon:

```
const addon = require('./addon/build/Release/addon');

addon.setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange(() => {
  console.info('setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange called');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  // This keeps the JS script alive for some time
  console.log('timedout');
}, 200000);
```

And this is my `binding.gyp` file, though I suspect it's relevant:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [
        "addon.mm",
      ],
      "xcode_settings": {
        "OTHER_CFLAGS": [
          "-ObjC++",
        ],
      },
      "link_settings": {
        "libraries": [
          "-framework Foundation",
          "-framework AVFoundation",
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis seems plausible to me: "when `setOnAudioOutputDeviceChange` returns, it deallocates (or something of the sort) the variables (context, cb, and isolate). And thus they're unusable outside of the function".

Those variables are held by the `jsCb` object, but you pass it in to `AudioObjectAddPropertyListener()` as the `context` which is a `void*`, so nothing is retaining that object. **Instead, try passing it as `(__bridge_retained void*)jsCb` or `CFBridgingRetain(jsCb)`**, which will increment the reference count before adding the callback. Then you can retrieve it in your audioOutputDeviceChanged function as `JSCallback *jsCb = (__bridge JSCallback *)inClientData;`, which will neither retain nor release it. Finally, **when removing the audio property listener you should release the object** via `__bridge_transfer` or `CFRelease`/`CFBridgingRelease`.

Bridged casts are described in documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html) and [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) and you can find more examples by searching Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Alternatively, rather than manually retaining/releasing the Obj-C object, you could restructure your code so that the Obj-C object lives as long as the whole Node module, by making a single `static` object that you initialize once (for example in your `Initialize` function) or creating it in `NODE_MODULE_INITIALIZER` for a "[context-aware addon](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_context_aware_addons)". Then you could use `__bridge` when passing this object as `void* context` and not worry about retaining and releasing.